# How to disable cd command-line?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, cd

Typing 'cd' alone in unix terminal leads to Home directory. I wish to disable this functionality. Usually I make the error of typing enter just after cd, and then each time I need to comback to the previous working directory. I loose a lot of time by doing so.

To go Home directory, one would instead just need to type cd ~.

Any idea please?

Comment: One method: Create a function called `mycd` that requires an argument.  Alias `cd` to `mycd`.  Put these two commands in your startup scripts.  You may not get useful concrete answers until you specify which shell(s) you want this to work in.

Comment: Note that when you do `cd` and then <enter>, you can go back to the previous dir with `cd -`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `cd -` to quickly return to the previous directory (`$OLDPWD`). In general, I recommend getting used to UNIX as it is. But if you really want to, add this function to `~/.bashrc`. It will make `cd` with no arguments a noop.

```
cd() {
    (( $# > 0)) && builtin cd "$@"
}
```

Comment: elegant bash solution :)

Comment: `cd () { [ $# -gt 0 ] && command cd "$@"; }` for POSIX compatibility, if desired.